# PowerShell won't remember my user settings

Tags: powershell

Did anyone had an issue with PowerShell that it won't remember your settings such as font, windows size e.g.?

I run PowerShell with another user (admin account) and set the console settings, but the next time I run PowerShell with the same user, I get the default settings again. I did try to use the "Defaults" option but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This is unrelated to powershell, but instead is a question about the underlying console host.

Comment: [See this article series for answers to your question](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/)

Answer (score -1):

If you type `$Profile` in your powershell session, it will tell your the location where it will load your profile from.

If you create a file on the suggested location it will be automaticly loaded in your session.
Here you can set settings like window size and all that.

```
$Shell = $Host.UI.RawUI
$Shell.WindowTitle="My window title"

$Shell = $Host.UI.RawUI
$size = $Shell.WindowSize
$size.width=120
$size.height=75
$Shell.WindowSize = $size
$size = $Shell.BufferSize
$size.width=100
$size.height=4500
$Shell.BufferSize = $size
```

To set a different font you'll have to change it on OS-level I believe. Not 100% about that one.

Hope it helps!